# Laravel 5.4 Show custom error message in login page

Tags: laravel-5, authentication, credentials

I modify the login function in Login controller using credentials function

```
protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        return ['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 1];
    }
```

although the function is work, but i need to return an error message to show that "Account is suspended" in login page if user's status not equal to 1.

How can i modify the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a middleware for that so you can use it. not only in your login function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Auth;

class CheckStatus
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user()->status != 1) {
        return redirect('yourloginpageroute')->withInfo("Account is suspended");
    }

    return $next($request);
}

}
```

Assuming that you have a status row in your auth.

Comment: but the session of user login already start, how do i prevent it? if the status is not active